# How redirect user to Error page with 404 status in Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, http-status-code-404, vue-router

I get some API data using Axios in Nuxt, I want to check inside the data, and if it hadn't what I want, redirect the user to the 404 not found page,

I wrote the below code but it doesn't work when I refresh the page
I found out that when I use Nuxt-link to go to the page redirecting to the 404 page works fine Only when runs server-side of nuxt (by refreshing the page) It doesn't work & I'll get errors because the data I was supposed to get will be null

I can't handle all those null situations everywhere on that page now, I must know that why computed methods runs faster than fetch when I refresh the page

```js
  fetch() {
    return this.getData()
  },
  
  methods: {
   this.coins = await this.$axios.$get('/api/public/prices', {timeout: 10000})
   let market = 'ADA_USDT'.split('_')
      if(this.coins[market[1]]){
         //call other API
      }else{
        //redirect user to error page with 404 status
        return this.$nuxt.error({ statusCode: 404, message: '404 Not Found' })
      }
  }
```

Comment: You have two problems: (1) the null issues in the computed props that cause errors; and (2) the 404 redirect. You need to solve the first issue before proceeding with the second. But your code shows nothing to troubleshoot the first issue.

Comment: I can solve the first issue & I'll but if redirecting to the 404 error page gets done successfully then the computed method should never run

Comment: I found out that when I use Nuxt-link to go to the page redirecting to the 404 page works fine
Only when runs server-side of nuxt (by refreshing the page) It doesn't work & I'll get those computed methods error